# How can I disable quick search in unity file explorer?

Tags: unity, search

When I'm exploring files and folders, and type some character, I would like, instead of open a search, to jump over the file or folder containing the name of the pressed key.

Sorry about my poor English explanation..

Thanks!

Comment: pcmanfm does that, I think.

Answer (score -3):

The issue is resolved in 14.04; wait for its release.